# Possible to cancel an Android notification after a few minutes?

Tags: android, notifications, cordova-3

I realize that cutting off a notification after an amount of time is odd and unexpected, but I am creating a Phonegap application for a user study group in which this functionality is necessary. I have tried several methods of achieving this through Phonegap background mode plugins but each has there own quirks and would not work reliably due to Android memory management.

What I am thinking now is that I will modify the Android side of this plugin:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

To cancel a notification after three minutes since it has triggered. I have talked to the developer of this plugin and he says it's not possible on his end but I don't mind trying to fix it myself. I don't have a lot of Android experience however, and am not sure if I would be wasting my time in trying. Is there any way this would work?

**Edit:**

I can go into further detail about what I have tried in the past, however I have arrived at the conclusion that these pursuits are dead ends-- They are all Phonegap plugin oriented and do not address the fundamental problem of Android's memory management system killing my running Javascript components that limit notification duration. Because of this, I figured I would change the Android side of my code.

Unfortunately, I have no experience in Android and have so far found learning Android daunting and the framework complex in my early research. It would be a waste of time to research an involved topic like the Android framework if it turns out that I cannot even do what I need to do. This is why I asked if it was possible or not; it is much easier and quicker for someone to tell me 'no', and obviate the need for me to research, than it is for me to research and understand a topic to the point that I can come to the conclusion myself.

Comment: I think what you need is to read this very good article, http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, there is a cancel method for notifications:

1. cancel() : - Cancel a previously shown notification
2. cancelAll () : - Cancel all previously shown notifications.